How should I determine the members of the following intersection types?
interface  A{
}
interface  B{
}
interface  C{
}
interface  D extends A,B,C{
}

If there is:
class N<T extends A & B & C>

According to the content of JLS 4.9:

Every intersection type T1 & ... & Tn induces a notional class or
interface for the purpose of identifying the members of the
intersection type, as follows:
• For each Ti (1 ≤ i ≤ n), let Ci be the most specific class or array
type such that Ti <: Ci. Then there must be some Ck such that Ck <: Ci
for any i (1 ≤ i ≤ n), or a compile-time error occurs.
• For 1 ≤ j ≤ n, if Tj is a type variable, then let Tj' be an
interface whose members are the same as the public members of Tj;
otherwise, if Tj is an interface, then let Tj' be Tj.
• If Ck is Object, a notional interface is induced; otherwise, a
notional class is induced with direct superclass type Ck. This class
or interface has direct superinterface types T1', ..., Tn' and is
declared in the package in which the intersection type appears.

For the meaning of "the most specific class", I only find relevant descriptions in 15.12.2.5:

A type S is more specific than a type T for any expression if S <: T
(§4.10).

First of all, what makes me suspect is whether Ci can be an interface type.(It is said here that Ci can only be a class or array type.)
If not, then I think Ci will be Object. But if so, I find that I can't determine what Ck is.
If it is possible, then:
T1 == C1 == A,
T2 == C2 == B,
T3 == C3 == C,
Ck == D.
So according to the specification, a notional class will be induced, and it has a direct superclass type Ck.
But Ck is not a class type, it is an interface.
I find that I can't correctly determine the members of the intersection type in any case, so I come here to seek help.
Thank you for your reading.

If they explicitly say class rather than type, I would suspect that Cₖ cannot be an interface. But that is only a suspicioun; I would need to read more context within this fairy technical document called JLS.

What makes you suspect that that Ci can be an interface when it explicitly tells you that Ci should be a "class or array type"?

@Sweeper I have read the answers to some other questions. For example,
this one.Is its answer correct?

C1, C2, and C3 are all Object. Ck is also Object.
Even if interface types were allowed, Ck could not be D, because Ck is supposed to be one of the Ci types. Instead, you would have a compile-time error.
Allowing the Ci types to be interface types would render most uses of intersection types invalid. There's a good reason the Ci types are restricted to class or array types, and not interface types.

Does Ck also have to be a class or array type? The specification doesn't seem to say that Ck must be a class or array type. So as long as Ck is a subtype of Object, wouldn't it be okay?

@user24723440: The idea is that k is an integer in the range 1 <= k <= n. Ck is one of the Ci types.
